# ActionBarSherlock change ProgressBar from external AsyncTask

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I want to set ProgressVisibility(true) in an AsyncTask. Is the AsyncTask in the Main, all is fine.

```
public class GlanceActivity extends SherlockActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //This has to be called before setContentView and you must use the
        //class in com.actionbarsherlock.view and NOT android.view
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_glance);
    }

    public class TestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<String>> {
        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {
            // Show IndeterminateProgressBar
            setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
            // Load some Data...
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> arg) {
            // Hide IndeterminateProgressBar
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        }
    }
}
```

But if I want to generate an Extra File for the AsyncTask, the setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility is undefined for GroupPageTask...

**How can I use this method in an seperate AsyncTask File?**

GlanceActivity.java

```
public class GlanceActivity extends SherlockActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //This has to be called before setContentView and you must use the
        //class in com.actionbarsherlock.view and NOT android.view
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_glance);
    }
}
```

GroupPageTask.java

```
public class GroupPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<String>> {
    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        // Show IndeterminateProgressBar
        setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Load some Data...
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> arg) {
        // Hide IndeterminateProgressBar
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Answer of [Matt Handys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620338/matt-handy), i found the right way...

*GlanceActivity.java*

```
public class GlanceActivity extends SherlockActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {
    public static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        GroupPageTask groupPageTask = new GroupPageTask(getSherlock());
    }
}
```

*GroupPageTask.java*

```
public class GroupPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<Mannschaft>> {
    private ActionBarSherlock sherlock;

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        // Show IndeterminateProgressBar
        sherlock.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Mannschaft> arg) {
        sherlock.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could hand over the context during AsyncTask construction:

```
public class GroupPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<String>> 
{
  private Context context;

  public AsyncTask(Context context) 
  {
    this.context = context;
  }

  protected void onPreExecute() 
  {
    ((Activity) context).setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> arg) 
  {
    ((Activity) context).setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
  }
}
```

Then create your AsyncTask with the new constructor from your activity:

```
GroupPageTask groupPageTask = new GroupPageTask(this);
```

Comment: I tried this and I had to use:   ActionBarSherlock: ((SherlockActivity) context).setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true); and for the ActionBar:   ((Activity) context).setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);